# PHP What is wrong with this function call?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an existing method, which is part of Wordpress:

```
function process_checkout() {
     global $wpdb, $wpdeals;
     $validation = $wpdeals->validation();
   ...
```

Now I want to extend this a bit, should really be childs play, not sure what I am doing wrong?

```
function process_checkout() {

        if (address_captured() == false)
        {
            echo '<script>alert("expected");</script>';
            exit;
        }

        global $wpdb, $wpdeals;
        $validation = $wpdeals->validation();
    ...
```

And (Simplified for testing)....

```
function address_captured()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Code stops executing around the if (address_captured() == false) line.

Can you spot anything out of the ordinary? Seems really 101 basics....

**EDIT**

It's not the exit statement either. Checked that too.

Comment: The semi-colon in `echo '<script>alert("expected");</script>';` just before `</script>` maybe?

Comment: @Fred, What makes you think that a semicolon is out of the ordinary?  Of course he can put a semicolon there.

Comment: That actually works... When tested without the function condition...

Comment: @JL., Check your error logs.  You'll probably find that `address_captured()` is undefined, meaning you're missing an include/require somewhere.

Comment: @Brad I said "maybe", I didn't say "for sure". ;-) It just seemed odd to me, that's all.

Comment: @Brad, I've put the function directly above process_checkout() in code....

Comment: @JL., What do your logs say?

Comment: Not sure where to check them, its a WP install...

Comment: Try the comparison with `===`

Comment: @JL. same place you would check for any other PHP error on the server error_log, if you have cPanel there should be available on your panel, if its your own server check what it is on the virtual host, usually it is on the error_log or log folder of your user if you have not set one then it is at /var/log/httpd/error_log

Comment: Since I'm pushed for time I just coded the function logic inside the calling function....

Comment: Have you tried having `address_captured()` return `true`?  If you try that, and the code you are expecting to fire off executes, it is because you are checking a boolean first in your if, not a variable or a return value.  Right now, it reads `if (false == false)`, which I think as soon as it sees the first false, the if fails to continue because if is looking for a boolean returned from the statement, not a boolean in the statement

Comment: Is it not possible that address_captured() is actually returning false?  I guess I should just ask if address_changed() is a function you created on your own or one that is built into WP.

Comment: its a function I built on my own, what you see in the example is exactly what was coded.